# How to make an event click only affect the icon that you are clicking

Tags: javascript, frontend

[Link to the form here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHgRC.png)
I have a form with a functionality with show/hide password, now i want the same on the repeat password input, in both i have an icon with an eye open/close. The problem is that when i click on the password one to show (and open the eye) also happens on the repeat password icon.

Is not affeting the functionality, thats already working since is not the same function, but im not able to make it only on the icon you are clicking since it has the same name and i cannot change it.

I tried to change the name of the icon but this icons cannot be named different (they are uploaded on a library and if you change the name it dissapear).

My code is:

```
`function revealPass() {
    document.getElementById("password").setAttribute("type", "text");
    $(".icon-ojo-abierto").removeClass("d-none");
    $(".icon-ojo-cerrado").addClass("d-none");
}

function hidePass() {
    document.getElementById("password").setAttribute("type", "password");
    $(".icon-ojo-cerrado").removeClass("d-none");
    $(".icon-ojo-abierto").addClass("d-none");
}

function revealPass2() {
    document.getElementById("passwordConfirmation").setAttribute("type", "text");
    $(".icon-ojo-abierto").removeClass("d-none");
    $(".icon-ojo-cerrado").addClass("d-none");
}

function hidePass2() {
    document.getElementById("passwordConfirmation").setAttribute("type", "password");
    $(".icon-ojo-cerrado").removeClass("d-none");
    $(".icon-ojo-abierto").addClass("d-none");
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will select *all* elements with the class "icon-ojo-abierto", even though you just want the icons that are beside a certain input field:

```
$(".icon-ojo-abierto").removeClass("d-none");
```

You did not post your HTML, so we can only guess about how it's structured, but assuming it looks something like this...:

```
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <input id="password" type="password" />
    <span class="icon-ojo-abierto"></span>
    <span class="icon-ojo-cerrado d-none"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input id="passwordConfirmation" type="password" />
    <span class="icon-ojo-abierto"></span>
    <span class="icon-ojo-cerrado d-none"></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

...you should be able to select just the relevant icons like so:

```
function revealPass() {
    document.getElementById("password").setAttribute("type", "text");
    const iconAbierto = document.querySelector('#password ~ .icon-ojo-abierto');
    iconAbierto.classList.remove('d-none');
    const iconCerrado = document.querySelector('#password ~ .icon-ojo-cerrado');
    iconCerrado.classList.add('d-none');
}
```

The key here is to use a selector which only matches with the element you need. In my example I'm using the general sibling combinator to only select `.icon-ojo-abierto` if there is a `#password` as it's sibling.